# Library to develop cross-platform desktop UI for a Python app

Tags: library, software-development, cross-platform, user-interface

I'm developing a password manager desktop application in python-tkinter, but tkinter hasn't a good looking UI. I'm looking for an alternative.

The main things that I want are the following:

1. Professional interface that looks nice.
2. Cross-plaftorm (I would like to run it either on Mac/Windows/Linux).
3. Active community behind the library.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note that recommendation of programming languages is off-topic here. For details, please see: [Should programming language recommendations be allowed here?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/36/185)

Comment: Do you want to develop the GUI yourself? If you use `argparse` to parse your command line arguments, there are a few apps which will scan your code, look for availabel arguments and generate a GUI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) allows for refined and attractive desktop apps for Windows, Mac and Linux using JavaScript, HTML and CSS.

1. Professional Interface: Yes. For example Visual Studio Code is built using Electron
2. Cross Platform: Yes
3. Good community support: Yes

[image: Visual Studio Code - written using Electron]

Comment: It looks nice! I'll take a look.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to use [Qt](https://www.qt.io/) which allows for it's UI to be converted to Python compatible.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429452/convert-pyqt-ui-to-python

With payment, you get customer support and some perks, but almost all Qt work you see "in the wild" is the GPLed (or LGPLed) version.

[image]

Comment: But Qt is paid no?

Comment: There is a paid and an open source version, please see the differences here https://www.qt.io/licensing-comparison/

Comment: @Lechucico: Essentially the answer is "No, you don't pay". With payment you get customer support and some perks, but almost all Qt work you see "in the wild" is the GPLed (or LGPLed) version. If it has Python bindings, I would really recomend it. See also [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(software)#Organizations_using_Qt) of organizations using it for much/all of their GUI work.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest taking a look at [wxPython](https://wxpython.org/) which is a set of python bindings for the [wxWidgets](https://www.wxwidgets.org/) GUI toolkit.

This provides a native look and feel on all of Windows, OS-X & Linux and can be used to produce very professional looking a GUI from python.

To get an introduction to wxPython for Python 2.7 download and install it **plus the documents & demo** suite.

Python 3 support is an in progress project called [Project Phoenix](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/index.html) that, while it is not yet at the first official release, works well to provide a very good, cross platform, GUI for most projects. Installation of the latest build can be done with the line:

```
pip install --upgrade --trusted-host wxpython.org --pre -f http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/snapshot-builds/ wxPython_Phoenix
```

but installation of the documents and demos package requires downloading the source from [github](https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/).

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Licence permits commercial use as well as personal & academic
- Cross Platform Windows, OS-X & Windows
- Native Look & Feel *utilises native components where ever possible*
- Large & Active user & developer communities
- Mature - wxPython initial release was in 1998!
- A lot of online help & books available
- Numerous Applications already using wxPython

### Example Apps

[PySpread](http://pyspread.sourceforge.net/) Pythonic Spreadsheet
[image]
[Cornice](http://wxglade.sourceforge.net/extra/cornice.html) Cross Platform Image Browser
[image]
[OpenDict](http://opendict.sourceforge.net/) Open Source multiplatform computer dictionary.
[image]

*All screenshots from the respective programs web site.*

Answer (score 1):

### [JavaFx](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FLkOX4Eez6o&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBzfXLWLSYVy8EbTdpGbUIG)

It's not python, but in conjunction with [Scene Builder](http://gluonhq.com/labs/scene-builder/) (see below) you can create simple professional-looking GUIs rapidly.

- **Easy**

  - Scene Builder provides a drag-n-drop interface which simplifies GUI design.
- **Code Friendly**

  - By giving a Scene Builder object an ID, you can reference it from a Java application to handle events, get content, change the scene graph, etc.
- **Cross-Platform**

  - Packaging the project in an executable jar makes it runnable on Windows, Linux, and Mac (if they have Java installed)
- **Free**

  - Java and Scene Builder are free
- **Active Community**

  - Java has a large user base and a lot of resources, the JavaFx subset is much smaller but still exists and is well documented.

[**Scene Builder**](http://gluonhq.com/labs/scene-builder/)
[image]

Comment: Which prominent apps use JavaFx?

Comment: Here is a list of some major apps developed in JavaFX - mostly internal and company-specific though. Not too many major open-source examples that I can find at the moment.

I'm currently working on a company-internal JavaFX application as well.


https://jaxenter.com/20-javafx-real-world-applications-123653.html